# Why does man page completion fail after su?

Tags: bash, debian, root, autocomplete, su

I have a default Debian 8.1 installation. 
I do

```
su
man apt<TAB>
```

but get nothing. 
I do see the manual when I write `man apt-get` in both modes: as user mas and as root. 
However, tab completion works in the user mode only.

How can I enable table completion after man in root? 
Why is this disabled by default?

Comment: If you do `su -` instead of `su`, does completion work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `su` invokes bash in non-login mode.  Bash then reads `.bashrc` to configure its environment.

Runing `su -` invokes bash as a login shell.  In this mode `/etc/profile` is executed if it exists.  Bash also searches for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` executing the first file it finds.  Although not documented, it appears to execute `~/.bashrc` when none of these exist.

If you get different behavior, it is likely that you are using different files to initialize bash depending on how it is invoked.

I tested which file was invoked by adding lines like `echo .bashrc` to then end of the existing files.  This will display which configurations get invoked.

There is more detail on this behavior in the INVOCATION section of the `bash` man page.

Tab completion is available in `bash` but not in `sh`.  `root` normally has `sh` as its shell as `bash` may not be available.  Users typically have `bash` as their shell.

Try running `bash` as `root` before trying tab-completion. This should enable tab completion.

Comment: root's shell is bash, in Debian 8. And completion does work if you `su -`, as Mark Plotnick suggested.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem and is wrong in several points. On a default Debian installation, root's shell is bash (I think that's been the case in all Debian releases). `.bashrc` is not read by a login shell (except for non-interactive login shells invoked by rshd or sshd, but then `.profile` and its cousins are not read).

Answer (score 2):

Bash has two completion engines: a simple one that mostly only does completion of commands in command position and file names in argument position, and a fancy one that completes arguments based on the command. To get man page completion, you need the fancy one.

When you start bash, only the simple completion engine is enabled. To get the fancy engine, you need to source `/etc/bash_completion`. This changes the historical behavior and adds to the startup time, which may be why this isn't the bash default.

In Debian, the instruction to read `/etc/bash_completion` is present in the default `.bashrc` for new accounts, but not in the system configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc`. It isn't put in the system configuration file because that would make it impossible for users to opt out of it. If you want the fancy completion system in shells running as root, you need to add this line to `/root/.bashrc`:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```